# Right way to retrieve model value in editortemplate

Tags: asp.net, mvc-editor-templates

Consider this editor template (even though it doesn't make sense - I have simplified it for clarity):

```
@Html.TextBox("", null)
```

This editor template should retrieve the name and the value for the element which it was called for. The name does get set correctly. The value, however, does not.

The data type differs - sometimes it is a double, sometimes it is a string. So I cannot declare a specific data type as the model.

The only way I can make it behave correctly is if I specify the type as dynamic:

```
@model dynamic

@Html.TextBox("", (string)Convert.ToString(Model))
```

This seems like a very clumsy syntax, although it works. Have I got it right?

**EDIT**:

The full code for my editortemplate is a textfield, that can dynamically be calculated by js ajax calls. It works perfectly, and is meant as a general template for any value that can be calculated from the value of other fields. It is **not necessarily a string type**. However, I need to provide an object for the argument of the Html.TextBox value.

```
@model dynamic

@{
    var CalcClasses = (@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("CalcClasses")) ? " " + @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["CalcClasses"] : "";
    var CalcUrl = (@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("CalcUrl")) ? @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["CalcUrl"] : "";
    var CalcDependsOn = (@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("CalcDependsOn")) ? @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["CalcDependsOn"] : "";
    var CalcTooltip = (@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("CalcTooltip")) ? @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["CalcTooltip"] : "";
}

<div class="calculated-field-container input-append">
    @Html.TextBox("", (string)Convert.ToString(Model), new 
        { @class="calculated-field" + CalcClasses, 
          data_calc_url = CalcUrl, 
          data_calc_dependencies = CalcDependsOn
        })
    <button class="btn button-calculate" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@CalcTooltip">=</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**:

Seems this works as well:

```
@{
    var CalcClasses = (@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("CalcClasses")) ? " " + @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["CalcClasses"] : "";
    var CalcUrl = (@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("CalcUrl")) ? @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["CalcUrl"] : "";
    var CalcDependsOn = (@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("CalcDependsOn")) ? @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["CalcDependsOn"] : "";
    var CalcTooltip = (@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("CalcTooltip")) ? @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["CalcTooltip"] : "";
}
<div class="calculated-field-container input-append">
    @Html.TextBox("", Model, new 
        { @class="calculated-field" + CalcClasses, 
          data_calc_url = CalcUrl, 
          data_calc_dependencies = CalcDependsOn
        })
    <button class="btn button-calculate" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@CalcTooltip">=</button>
</div>
```

Comment: A few things, just to get a better grasp: 1) Can you use a better example than @Html.TextBox("",null) as it doesn't make it clear what your problem is? 2) Model is dynamic by default. 3) To clarify: you are returning a different data type every time using the same view, but displaying it as a `string`? Why not use @model string? Or a ViewModel holding a string?

Comment: You put me on the right track. Model does the trick, if I just do not declare the model type. Alternatively, model object would work as well.

Comment: Correction: I need to declare model as object, otherwise it fails.

Comment: Good work on the extra info. The ViewModel could have the CalcXXXX as properties themselves, and then it will save you putting in this ContainsKey() ?? logic into the View.

Comment: True. But this approach allows me to define all the properties in the model as data annotations, and use this single view for all calculated fields.